# How to get counts in facebook graph queries

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

say i want to find our number of people interested in dancing and live in san francisco, i can type "people interested in dancing and live in san francisco" and facebook displays me the users matching the criteria. How can get a count on the total users selected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do counts with the Graph API. Please don't confuse the Graph Search with the Graph API.

The searches you can perform with the Graph API are very limited compared to what you can do in the Facebook frontend: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search